# Configure Jenkins pipeline job when PR is merged to master branch - Bitbucket

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I would like to trigger a Jenkins job when there is bit bucket master branch merge only. Now, Job is getting triggered when raise a PR in bit bucket, but it is not get triggered when the PR is merged.

Configured Jenkins job as multi branch pipeline. I would like to know whether is this correct way to configure the job or any other way to achieve this functionality.

Please see the jenkins and bitbucket configuration screen shots attached.

[image]
[image].

Any help will be appreciated